# VERACODE External Control of file name of path issue

Tags: asp.net, path, controls, external, filenames

I am developing an application in asp.net. When scanning with Veracode's application for one of my functions shows the following error "External Control of File Name or Path". 
Anyone know how to fix this error?

```
 public void UploadFileToTemp(Stream streamFile, string fileName)
    {


        if (!Directory.Exists( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderName"]))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Temp");
        }

        string name = MakeValidFileName(fileName);
        string path = MakeValidPathName( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderName"] , name);
        FileStream fileStream = File.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderName"]+"TEstSubida1", (int)streamFile.Length);
        // Initialize the bytes array with the stream length and then fill it with data
        byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[streamFile.Length];
        streamFile.Read(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
        // Use write method to write to the file specified above
        fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
        fileStream.Close();
        fileStream.Dispose();
    }
```